# How to exclude error data from matrix and include fitted values- Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-fitting

I need to exclude some error data from matrix. I know what data is correct and i am trying to interpolate values between so I can get decent diagrams with not so big errors. I must use that form of matrix and I must preserve its shape. I must only substitute some data that is marked as errors. I will show you my work so far:

```
M=[0.1000
0.6000
0.7000
0.8000
0.9000
0.9500
1.0000
1.0500
1.1000
1.1500
1.2000
1.2500
1.3000
1.5000
1.7500
2.0000
2.2500
2.5000
3.0000];

CZ1=[ 9.4290
9.5000
9.3250
9.2700
9.2950
9.4350
9.6840
10.0690
10.1840
10.2220
10.2160
9.6160
9.6890
9.4880
9.5000
9.5340
9.3370
9.0990
8.5950];

N1=11;
Nn=13;

Mx1=M(N1);
Mx2=M(Nn);
Mx=[Mx1 Mx2]';
CN1=CZ1(N1);
CN2=CZ1(Nn);
CNy=[C1 C2]';

y1=interp1q(Mx,CNy,M(N1:Nn));

CNf=CZ1;

NEWRangeC=y1;


Cfa=changem(CZ1,[NEWRangeC], [CNf(N1:Nn)]);

figure
plot(M,Cf,'-*b',M,Cfa,'r')
```

So far as you can see I used points 11 and 13 and i excluded point 12 interpolating that point from 11 to 13. This is working but i want to make a modification.

**My question is**: How can I select values that are errors and remove them but interpolate space between their neighbors. I want to use a M matrix values as my reference (not points as my example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know which elements are incorrect, you can use Matlab's `interp1` function to interpolate them (this will only work if the `M` matrix is actually a vector`:

```
error_indices = [11 13];

all_indices = 1:length(M)

% Get the indices where we have valid data
all_correct_indices = setdiff(all_indices, error_indices)

% the first two arguments are the available data. 
% the third arguments is what indices you are looking for 
M_new = interp1(all_correct_indices, M(all_correct_indices), all_indices)
```

The above interpolates values at `all_indices` -- including the missing elements. Where you already have valid data (`all_correct_indices`), Matlab will return that data. In other places, it will interpolate using the two nearest neighbors.

Try `help interp1` for more information on how this function works.

#### Update - an example

```
 x = 1:10; % all indices
 y = x*10;  

 e = 3:7;  % the unknown indices
 s = setdiff(x, e);  % the known indices

 y_est = interp1(s, y(s), x)

 ans =
    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100
```

And we see that interp1 had interpolated all values from 30 to 70 linearly using the available data (specifically the adjacent points 20 and 80).

Comment: I tried it and it is working but...
When I use `error_indices = [3 4 5 6 7]; ` I don't get linear interpolation from point 2 to point 8?
And i used next modification:
`CNf_new = interp1(all_correct_indices, CNf(all_correct_indices), all_indices)`
Cnf is also a vector as M.

Comment: @silent_bob: added example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can start out by finding the elements that are errors, with the `find` command (this will return the indices).  This should also work for matrices.

You can then grab the elements around each of the indices, and interpolate between, as you did.

Comment: How can i grab the elements? 
I know points that are errors. I need to replace them.